# Caught in an infinite loop solving reader writer prob

Tags: infinite-loop, xterm

I am working on reader-writer problem. Algorithm wise, i believe the solution is ok. The only problem that I am facing is opening multiple readers/writer windows using xterm. When I run the program it goes into an infinite loop and it crashed the whole system. It also open multiple xterm windows. It might be silly and simple, but I just don't seem to be able to figure out why? I've been thinking about this since yesterday. How do i fix this problem? The suspected area of conflict is highlighted with ** comments...

```
#include <unistd.h>     /* Symbolic Constants */
#include <sys/types.h>  /* Primitive System Data Types */ 
#include <errno.h>      /* Errors */
#include <stdio.h>      /* Input/Output */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* General Utilities */
#include <pthread.h>    /* POSIX Threads */
#include <string.h>     /* String handling */
#include <semaphore.h>  /* Semaphore */


//Global Variablels
int rc = 0;
int wc = 0;

sem_t m1, m2, m3, w, r; //Semphore


int reader() {
sem_wait(&m3);
sem_wait(&r);
sem_wait(&m1);
rc++;
if(rc == 1) sem_wait(&w);
sem_post(&m1);
sem_post(&r);
sem_post(&m3);
system("xterm -e ./read");
//execlp("xterm", "-e", "./ahor2r", NULL);
sem_wait(&m1);
rc--;
if(rc == 0) sem_post(&w);
sem_post(&m1);
return 0;
}



int writer() {
    sem_wait(&m2);
    wc++;
    if(wc == 1) sem_wait(&r);    
    sem_post(&m2); 
    sem_wait(&w);
    //system("xterm -e ./write"); //writing is performed
    execlp("xterm", "-e", "./ahor2w", NULL);    
    sem_post(&w);
    sem_wait(&m2);
    wc--;
    if(wc == 0)  sem_post(&r);
    sem_post(&m2);
    return 0;
}



int main() {
int ch;
sem_init(&m1, 0, 1); 
sem_init(&m2, 0, 1); 
sem_init(&m3, 0, 1); 
sem_init(&w, 0, 1); 
sem_init(&r, 0, 1); 
/*****************************************************************************
**********infinite loop*******************************************************/
while(1) {
    printf("\n\nEnter your option\n\n1> Create Reader\n2> Create Writer\n 3> Exit\n\t");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if(ch == 1)
        switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("Cannot fork a new reader process\n");
        break;
    case 0:
        reader();
    }
else if (ch == 2) 
    switch(fork()) {
    case -1:
            perror("Cannot fork a new reader process\n");
            break;
    case 0:
        writer();
    }
else if (ch == 3) {
    sem_destroy(&m1);
    sem_destroy(&m2);
    sem_destroy(&m3);
    sem_destroy(&w); 
    sem_destroy(&r); 
    return 0;
    }
else printf("INVALID OPTION - no action taken\n");
}
/*****************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************/
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two big errors:

1. You don't create your semaphores in shared memory. So each process gets its own copy of the semaphores, which makes no sense.
2. You don't create process-shared semaphores. The `0` in `sem_init` means that the semaphores will not be shared between processes. But `fork` creates new processes.

> If  pshared  has  the  value  0,  then the semaphore is shared between the threads of a process[.] If  pshared  is  nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see shm_open(3), mmap(2), and shmget(2)).